# How to pass textarea content using TinyMCE through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've recently discovered a problem when submitting forms using TinyMCE Jquery-plugin. When trying to submitting normal input fields such as text fields, select boxes and so on, everything works as it should. However, using TinyMCE on a textarea doesn't work correctly; i have to submit two times to save. Is there a fix for this particular problem?

```
<script>
 $(function () {
     $('.message').removeClass('hidden');
 });
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      //save button so we can use later
      var my_button = $(this).find("button");

      //give button loading state
      my_button.button('loading');

      e.preventDefault();

      var note = $("#content").text();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        url: '/m/core/_processEditEntry.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

          //reset state
          my_button.button('reset');

          $(".message").fadeIn(0);
          $(".message").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

---

HTML

```
<textarea id="cotent" name="content" style="width:100%"><?php echo $entry->content; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: you should use `$('#tinymce').tinymce().getContent()`

Comment: @Dagon How should I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question.

I needed to add `tinyMCE.triggerSave();`

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      //save button so we can use later
      var my_button = $(this).find("button");

      //give button loading state
      my_button.button('loading');

      e.preventDefault();
      tinyMCE.triggerSave();
      var note = $("#content").text();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        url: '/m/core/_processEditEntry.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

          //reset state
          my_button.button('reset');

          $(".message").fadeIn(0);
          $(".message").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```